# Prove the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other

Tags: proof-writing, vectors, solution-verification, proof-explanation

When the two diagonals intersect together, aren't they cutting it into 4 equal parts and not 2?

And to prove that they bisect, you would just need to find the midpoint and see if half of the length of the diagonal is exactly half so that it reaches the midpoint. It just doesn't seem like a proof at all to me?

Can someone help me with these 2 seperate but related questions?

Comment: Both diagonals cut the other one in half: we get two pairs of equal segments, but all 4 parts are usually not equal (only for rectangles).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a parallelogram with diagonals drawn through E (not shown due to difficulty).

```
    /A----------------B
   /                 /
  /        E        /
 /                 /
D----------------C/
```

- Since AB and DC are parallel, angle ACD and CAB are congruent.
- Likewise, angles BDC, ABD are congruent
- We know that CD and AB are congruent because they are the sides of a  parallelogram

By ASA (Angle-Side-Angle), triangles ABE and CDE are congruent. Therefore

- EC is congruent to AE
- BE is congruent to DE

They are not equal unless the parallelogram is a rectangle.