# Proof of the fact that the diagonals of a parallelogram have the same middle

Tags: solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, education

I teach mathematics in a Parisian school. My students are twelve years old and are sometimes very bright children. That is why I am looking for a demonstration that is both mathematically correct and adapted to their knowledge of the fact that the diagonals of a parallelogram ABCD have the same middle. This is an affine result and I don't want to use metric results to do it.
I use as definition of *parallelogram*: "*quadrilateral whose opposite sides are parallel*".
I propose in particular, in addition to the usual axioms such as that *through a point there passes a single line parallel to a given line*, the following axiom:
*the image of a line by a central symmetry is a parallel line*.

---

Here is what I propose: consider a parallelogram $ABCD$; call $O$ the midpoint of the diagonal $[AC]$ and then "work in $ABC$": $B\in (AB)$ and $A\to C$ by the symmetry $s_O$ of centre $O$. So $s_O(B)$ belongs to the image of $(AB)$ by $s_O$ which is a line that passes through $C$ and is parallel to $(AB)$ according to the axiom: "the image of a line by a central symmetry is a parallel line." Thus, since there is a single line parallel to $(AB)$ through $C$ according to the other axiom recalled, it must be $(CD)$ (1) [note: the definition of the parallelogram $ABCD$, "a quadrilateral whose opposite sides are parallel", was used here]. Similarly, $B\in(BC)$ and $C\to A$ so $s_O(B)$ belongs to $(AD)$ (2). Therefore, from (1) and (2), $s_O(B)\in (CD)\cap (AD)=\{D\}$. Therefore $s_O(B)=D$. Therefore the midpoint of $[BD]$ is $O$, by definition of central symmetry of centre $O$. Therefore the common midpoint of $[BD]$ and $[AC]$ is $O$. qed∎

---

Is this demonstration mathematically correct? Can we simplify it to make it as accessible as possible to as many 12 year olds as possible?

Comment: I would use basic geometry, alternate angle, and congruent triangle to prove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020002/prove-the-diagonals-of-a-parallelogram-bisect-each-other)

Comment: @AbelWong: why not ? but I don't want to use metric results (angle, congruent triangle, ... ) because it is an "affine result".

Comment: You don't need angle _measures_, and you don't need the full power of congruent triangles. You only need the part that's actually affine. Such as vertical angles being congruent.

Comment: How do you define midpoint without defining “distance”?

Comment: @insipidintegrator : that's a good question. Can we not consider the notion of the midpoint as a primary notion, i.e. a notion that does not require a definition but is self-evident?

Comment: "Two segments are parallel and congruent" is an entirely affine property, and can easily be used to define a midpoint without resorting to measures.

Comment: @ Stéphane Jaouen: Your proof is ok and is the same as [that of Troyanov, *Cours de géométrie*, p. 14](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3Qgzr6-dUocC&pg=PA14) found as a [reference on french Wikipedia about Parallelogram](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parall%C3%A9logramme#Notes_et_r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rences). @Arthur [Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)) is not a purely [affine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry) notion.

Comment: @AnneBauval It is when the segments you compare are parallel, and parallelism is affine. I stand by my statement.

Comment: @Arthur Are you saying that congruence of segments is parallelism? If so, I don't understand your "Two segments are parallel *and* (?) congruent". And if [two segments are congruent when they have the same *length*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)), this is not an affine notion, contrarily of course to parallelism.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't see how what I'm saying is difficult to understand. It is an affine property whether segments are parallel, and for parallel segments, congruence is affine. From this follows almost trivially an affine notion of midpoint. And congruence is miles more fundamental than length in most modern treatments of axiomatic geometry, so you really, really don't need a notion of length to make sense of congruence.

Comment: @Arthur Please, what is *your* definition of congruence for parallel segments?

Comment: @AnneBauval If there is a translation that makes one segment equal to what the other was before the translation. The standard geometric definition of congruence, just without rotation.

Comment: (and without reflexion). Oh! Then I agree of course (and "parallel" is redundant), and if your primary notion is translation, you can even define midpoints directly with it. But all this may seem circular from Stéphane's point of view.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think I have grasped all the subtleties of your exchange, @Anne Bauval and @Arthur; Anne must know that I am trying to betray as little as possible the fact that in a real vector space, (a,b,c,d) is a parallelogram if and only if b-a=c-d iff b+d=a+c iff 1/2(b+d)=1/2(a+c).

Comment: If I may, I would like to add that "middle point" is a particular case of barycentres, which is a purely affine notion. In fact, it is essentially **the** most important affine notion. Subtleties about barycentres are however way out of reach of these pupils

Comment: @Didier : yw. How do you define the midpoint without using a distance in the plane? I attempted an answer below, I would appreciate your opinion on this answer.

Comment: As I said, it is really out of reach for pupils, and in fact, it is out of reach for most students nowadays (at least in the French educational system): if you are interested, you can have a glance at [this](http://letendre.perso.math.cnrs.fr/docs/2017-agreg/GeoAgreg-2017-cours.pdf), section 2.2 (I am not the author of these notes). As for your answer below, I think it is good!

Comment: Essentially, the idea is the one you used in your answer but with a robust (and maybe overly pedantic?) formalism (i.e an affine plane is a space on which $\Bbb R^2$ acts simply and transitively), and it does not involve any euclidean geometry in the sense it only uses the algebraic structure of $\Bbb R$ as a field, that is, any non-zero real number has an inverse

Comment: @Didier : Overly pedantic or not, I'm sure that some of my pupils would surprise you, whether their parents work or have worked at Ulm or Polytechnique or not. And even for others, doing things square is less effort for me.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Sure they might be really clever, but I think that the notion of simply transitive action of a vector space over an abstract set (definition of affine space) and the use of the unique preimage of $0$ by an abstract map (definition of barycentre) can be out of reach for most pupils though, regardless of the prestigious background of their parents! However, I'm sure that there must be something more elementary to define properly these notions somewhere, and that I'm just not aware of that. Anyway, I wish I had a teacher as you spending this time taking care of saying right things

Comment: @Didier : I think we misunderstand each other (for me certainly the poor command of English, I use Google translation...) I wrote in my answer : "what do the pupils ? They place the zero of their ruler on one end of the segment, associate a number with the segment, which they divide in two. " I don't have the stupid pretension of giving a university course to twelve-year-olds. :) [sorry for "my" english]

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Right, nevermind! I wasn't assuming you were trying to teach them univ. courses. Sometimes the mathematical justification can be really simple while the intuition might not. I think affine geometry is at the exact opposite: your pupils do really have the intuition, as shows the sentence you have quoted. And no worries about your English ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments of @Insipidintegrator, @Arthur, @Anne Bauval, the only thing left to settle is to define the midpoint of a segment to the pupils without using a distance *in the plane*.
If I have understood correctly, the support of the segment, in other words the straight line, is identified with the field $\mathbb{R}$ associated with the affine plane and it suffices to have defined the middle of a segment there: what do the pupils ? They place the zero of their ruler on one end of the segment, associate a number with the segment, which they divide in two. How do we translate this mathematically up to a translation? Let $x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}$; the midpoint of $[xy]$ is $x+\frac{y-x}2=\frac{x+y}2=\frac12x+\frac12y$.

That suits me. As I wrote in a comment above, I am trying to betray as little as possible the fact that in a real vector space, $(a,b,c,d)$ is a parallelogram $\iff b-a=c-d \iff b+d=a+c \iff \frac12(b+d)=\frac12(a+c)$